# Need Help in Writing a Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

I have a table wich keep phone call records. I need to get answered and not answered calls count for each hour ( example 8:00 to 9:00 ) in specificed date range ( example 1 march to 5 march ), i dont need to separate the date, just need to separate hours.

Already i used this query:

```
SELECT `event`, DATE(`time`) AS `date`, HOUR(`time`) AS `hour`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `queue_log` WHERE `queuename` = 'Hozoori_Q' AND `event` IN ('CONNECT', 'RINGNOANSWER') AND `time` >= '2014-03-01' AND `time` <= '2014-03-05' GROUP BY `event`, `date`, `hour`;
```

the "event" field is call status.

this query output is something like this:

```
1 => 
array (size=4)
'event' => string 'CONNECT' (length=7)
'date' => string '2014-03-01' (length=10)
'hour' => string '9' (length=1)
'count' => string '99' (length=2)
2 => 
array (size=4)
'event' => string 'RINGNOANSWER' (length=7)
'date' => string '2014-03-01' (length=10)
'hour' => string '9' (length=1)
 'count' => string '5' (length=2)
```

but i want to be like this:

```
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'date' => string '2014-03-01' (length=10)
      'hour' => string '9' (length=1)
      'answered_count' => string '99' (length=2)
      'not_answered_count' => string '5' (length=2)
```

is there any solution ?

Comment: please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: Do you need this as an SQL, or a simple bit of PHP code to manipulate your current result array?

Comment: @Mark: I need this as a SQL result instead of using php loops.

Comment: @raheelshan: my desired output is second example array that mention above, the data are store on the table which contain too many fields, but the important fields are, time and event, wich if event = CONNECT means call is answered and if event = RINGNOANSWER means call was not answered.

Comment: @Ordidaad - I was uncertain as you'd tagged this both `mysql` and `arrays`, suggesting that an array manipulation in PHP would have been as valid a reply as a SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight SQL answer:

```
SELECT DATE(`time`) AS `date`, 
       HOUR(`time`) AS `hour`, 
       SUM(`event` = 'CONNECT') AS `answered_count`, 
       SUM(`event` = 'RINGNOANSWER') AS `not_answered_count` 
  FROM `queue_log` 
 WHERE `queuename` = 'Hozoori_Q' 
   AND `event` IN ('CONNECT', 'RINGNOANSWER') 
   AND `time` >= '2014-03-01' 
   AND `time` <= '2014-03-05'
 GROUP BY `date`, `hour`;
```

Comment: My bad: replace the COUNT() with SUM() as in my updated answer

Comment: thanks Mark, it work, so can i add SUM or AVG of other field where event = 'connect' to this query ? this filed show call duration of answered calls and this field name is data1 in my table

Comment: You can: `SUM(data1) / SUM(event = 'CONNECT') AS average_call_time` will be valid as long as data1 has 0 value for unanswered calls